# How to determine if an activity was opened by AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager

In my application there are 2 options to open the app.
One of them is open the app manually and start playing audio stream,
the other is to set an AlarmManager which will start the same activity in a defined time.

I figured out that to suspend the app I should use the AlarmManager.
I need to determine how did the user open the app (By itself using the AlarmManager, or manually).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Extend Application` class and Create static field which can be used as a flag (started from activity or from AM).. and then create getters and setters... now `set it true if started from actvity false if from Alarm manager`.. The advantage here is Application class will be visible all over the application and is a Single Instance,..

Comment: Which class should extend application?

Comment: How can I set the false flag? all the callbacks in the activity class passes onCreate on both cases

Comment: I forgot to mention that each of the cases the app starts from the beginning (not returning from background). Will the applicationContext remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify an intent when scheduling an app start by AlarmManager. If you specify an intent action different from android.intent.action.MAIN you'll be able to determine how the app was launched.